# How to pass C++ values in real time to JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, esp8266

I have an "Esp8266 nodeMCU" wifi module (similar to an Arduino) on a breadboard with usb connection to the official "Arduino IDE". [image]
And now I would like to grab the values (C++) coming from the module into my JavaScript code (the visible values in Arduino IDE's "Serial Monitor").

For example, when I release/press a button connected on my breadboard, a zero/one signal is sent through my module to Arduino's IDE...and from that point I would like to be able to access that value through my webpage in real time.[image]

I've heard that I could probably send the value through the module's WiFi section into the so called "RabbitMQ" messaging client, then into a local Raspberry Pi at home that goes into a local server and finally into my computer...woah!!
For a junior web developer that's a pretty long and bumpy road to take just to deliver candy to a store XD

...any "easier" suggestions?

---

**UPDATE !!!**

More specific info below (as requested by 'user3392724'):

- Did not write my own code for this project (for now), I'm using the existing code that comes built in the Arduino IDE (Arduino-based (C++)).
- My setup is now Esp8266 + breadboard + macbook pro (Arduino IDE on the mac) and on mac I have AMPPS.
- For now I run all my javascript project on Apache server (AMPPS localhost) which is sufficient to run things on but would be cool to later on reach the C++ values on live sites as well.
- As first stage I will have everything on my home network only.
- I will be the only user for this "experiment" as of now but if successful I will try to expand my horizons ;)

Answer (score 1):

Answer updated twice now, first after clarifications of the question, second after I realized some details were in fact mentioned in the question (e.g., a button is used).

When you say you are using 'the existing code' from the Arduino IDE, I assume you mean an example sketch to read a button.

What I understand you want is, for this read data to end up in a web page, using JavaScript to acquire/update the data in the page. This web page should be hosted on a server, not the ESP.

This means the first question is via which path/steps to move the data.
It can move via a server (for example your Apache server), or via multiple servers, like the RabbitMQ option. The advantage of involving a server is that the client, your web browser, only has to talk to the server. The server then talks to the ESP. This means you can use this solution from anywhere where you can just reach the server.

But in your case I would go for the 'easier' option, getting the data directly from the ESP. Your server serves the web page/JavaScript. And the JavaScript in the web page gets the data directly from the ESP (from inside your web-browser). The downside of this is that it only works if both the ESP and the server are reachable from your browser.

Another important choice to make is whether this data will be push or pull, does the ESP push each reading, or does the server/browser pull the data from the ESP. This depends how 'real-time' the result should be. A button is a bit trickier in this then a sensor, since a 'click' can be very short. Although there's several ways to work around that also, like keeping a counter which goes up for each click, and retrieving that value 'slowly'.
Pull sounds easier in your case, since you can just have a timer in your JavaScript, which requests the values from the ESP, and the ESP just needs to respond to the request with the current value. Push would be harder, because a web browser can't be pushed to, you would have to involve some kind of server which handles the push, stores the value, and then allows it to be retrieved by the web browser's JavaScript. So for now I'm assuming pull.

A last thing to consider is the amount of users. The ESP is quite limited in how many simultaneous connections it can handle (5 I think), with just one user this shouldn't be a problem. With many users it won't be able to handle the requests, which means the above options won't work. Instead you will need to have a server get the data from the ESP, store it, and then provide it to all the users, quite a bit more complicated :)

Now the 'easiest' option would be to have a small web server on the ESP, which does nothing more then read your value (sensor, click counter, etc.) on each request, and then return the value. You should be able to call this web server from your JavaScript, possibly on a timer.

I expect these are many examples of code to do this on Arduino.
I found two possible ones, but can't check since I'm behind a proxy:
http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Super-Simple-Arduino-Weather-Web-Server/
http://www.instructables.com/id/Measure-temperature-on-the-web-with-Arduino-Ethern/

If this option doesn't meet your requirements, update your question with the requirements, and I'll see if I can suggest something else ;)

Good luck!